# Several default packages in Java

Tags: java, package

I have a question concerning **default packages** in Java.

It is written in Java SE 8 specification:

> An implementation of the Java SE platform must support at least one
>   unnamed package. An implementation may support more than one unnamed
>   package, but is not required to do so. Which compilation units are in
>   each unnamed package is determined by the host system.

see section 7.4.2 in [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf).

I.e. it is possible to have more than one unnamed package.
As I understand Oracle implementation of Java 8 SE has only one unnamed package.

Do you know, is this feature is implemented somewhere?
Or do you have any idea how it could be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they leave the details of implementing the feature up to Java implementors.
But there is no any of such implementation yet.

Note:
Of cource we can have several source folders: src1, src2, ..., srcN but all of them share the same default package.
See, for example, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html